# Why is my flex layout horizontal instead of vertical?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been practicing html and CSS, and am trying to replicate this website:
https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/VPaoNP

However, I'm a bit stuck with flexbox and am confused as to why my h1, h2, and my 'survey-form' class suddenly turn into inline elements when I set display: flex.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #bdb2ff;
  display: flex;
}

.survey-form {
  background-color: #a0c4ff;
}
```

```html
<h1>freeCodeCamp Survey Form</h1>
<h2>Thank you for taking the time to help us improve the platform</h2>

<div class="survey-form">
  <form action="none">
    <p>
      <label for="username">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="age">Age (optional)</label>
      <input type="email" id="age" placeholder="Age">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

everything seems fine up until i set the body to display:flex. the h1's, h2's and my form all go in the same line. below are the pictures before and after setting display:flex

[image: the picture before display: flex]
[image: the picture after display: flex]

Answer (score 4):

Add `flex-direction: column;` to your code and uncomment your alignment.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #bdb2ff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.survey-form {
  background-color: #a0c4ff;
}
```

```html
<h1>freeCodeCamp Survey Form</h1>
<h2>Thank you for taking the time to help us improve the platform</h2>

<div class="survey-form">
  <form action="none">
    <p>
      <label for="username">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="age">Age (optional)</label>
      <input type="email" id="age" placeholder="Age">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Please also check out this guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/